# Parlour palm has gone pale and tips are brown

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, watering, palm

My parlour palm was nice and green for a few weeks but its leaves have recently turned pale and some of the tips have gone brown. Some of the leaves also seem to be curling.

Some of the stalks and leaves seem to be dying altogether.

I have it in a light room but away from the window.

I am worried I have overwatered it. Will it come back to life if I don't water it?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be in a plastic pot inside a cache pot. I recommend that you pull the inner pot out and dump out any water that might be sitting in it. After watering let the plant sit outside of the cache pot (setting it in the kitchen sink works well) for about an hour so the water can drain out and air can re-enter the soil. Before the next watering make sure to check the soil, the top layer should be dry, and when you stick your finger into the soil it should be damp about an inch down but not wet. If it's still wet then skip watering and check back in a day or so. If it's bone dry you may need to water more often.

I also recommend adding some balanced fertilizer the next time you water to help it green up a little bit. If you don't fertilize regularly then start with 1/2 strength. I use a balanced fertilizer once a month with a 10-10-10 npk rating for most houseplants.